# Spring websocket end-poind and send message

Tags: java, spring, websocket, sockjs, spring-websocket

I have an JMS listener, and I have to take the message, manipulate it and then redirect it to an page using websocket.

Well, I’m just confused about the configuration, I have configured the WebSocketConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@EnableScheduling
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
   @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic", "/queue");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws/firstep/").withSockJS();
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws/secondep/").withSockJS();
    }
```

And this it should be correct, Then my webpage is:

```
var socket = new SockJS("/myapp-web/api/ws/secondep/",undefined,options);
    var stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    stompClient.connect({
        company : "xxx"
    }, function(frame) {
        console.log('Connected: ' + frame);

          stompClient.subscribe('/topic/register', function(message){ 
            console.log('message: ' + message);     
          });

        stompClient.subscribe('/topic/update', function(message){ 
            console.log('message: ' + message);     
        });
```

And the connection works.

Now On my jms listener I tried to send a message in this way:

```
public class ImporterListener implements MessageListener {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ImporterListner.class);
    @SendTo("/topic/register")
    private String TestMessage() {
        return "TestMessage";
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        logger.info("Request on message");
        if (message instanceof MapMessage) {
            MapMessage t = (MapMessage) message;
             TestMessage(); //<--- have to send the message here
```

But it doesn’t work. 
The questions are:

1. How to send a message?
2. Where do I have to specify the end point (secondep) when I send a message?

Thank you! any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> TestMessage(); //<--- have to send the message here

No, it has't to send, because you use method from the same class, but `@SendTo` makes your `ImporterListener` as proxy and `Advice` will work on method only from another component.

You should inject this:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("brokerMessagingTemplate")
private MessageSendingOperations brokerMessagingTemplate;
```

And send a message using that:

```
brokerMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/register", "TestMessage");
```

> Where do I have to specify the end point (secondep) when I send a message?

It is for the `@MessageMapping("/ws/secondep")` on some POJO method to receive message from clients. It isn't for the sending part.